OpenMP 5 offloading C++ struct with member functions and data pointers
I have used OpenMP in a number of my past projects. Separately, I have also written CUDA and OpenCL GPU codes in a number of open source projects.
I've heard a lot that OpenMP 5 added support to NVIDIA/AMD GPU, and started some experiments in porting my CUDA/OpenCL codes to OpenMP5, but got stuck when offloading the code to nvidia GPU. I think I might have missed some basics, hence seeking some pointers here.
I decided to use C++ for this project. My full source code (~400 lines of C++ codes) can be accessed at https://github.com/fangq/umcx
To compile/test the code, one should run
git clone https://github.com/fangq/umcx.git
cd umcx/src
make           # build multi-threading without gpu offloading
./umcx cube60  # running the benchmark

the above multi-threaded version can be built/run properly on g++ 11 or newer. The code also works on NVIDIA GPU when built with nvc using
make clean
make nvc
./umcx cube60

However, I got many problems when trying to build it using g++-12/13 for nvptx-none, for example, if I run
make clean
make nvidia CXX=g++-12

[Update Dec 31, 2024] The missing sinf math function error was fixed by adding -foffload="-lm" as suggested by Mat Colgrove in the below comment.
Now g++-12 was able to produce a valid binary, however, running it produces the below memory error
$ make nvidia CXX=g++-12
g++-12  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=nvptx-none -foffload="-lm" -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -c umcx.cpp -o umcx.o
g++-12  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=nvptx-none -foffload="-lm" -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -o umcx umcx.o
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2w2usX.crtoffloadtable.o: warning: relocation against `__offload_funcs_end' in read-only section `.rodata'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
$ ./umcx cube60
libgomp: cuCtxSynchronize error: an illegal memory access was encountered
libgomp: cuMemFree_v2 error: an illegal memory access was encountered
libgomp: device finalization failed

running compute-sanitizer ./umcx cube60, it reports many memory reading errors for line#185 of the code
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4 bytes
=========     at main$_omp_fn$1+0x14f0 in umcx.cpp:185
=========     by thread (0,4,0) in block (25,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7f7f651712d0 is out of bounds
=========     and is 522,050 bytes after the nearest allocation at 0x7f7f64c00000 of size 5,184,399 bytes

Interestingly, g++-12 was also able to build an amdgcn offloaded binary with the same warning as above.
$ make amd CXX=g++-12
g++-12  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=amdgcn-amdhsa="-march=gfx906" -foffload="-lm" -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -c umcx.cpp -o umcx.o
g++-12  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=amdgcn-amdhsa="-march=gfx906" -foffload="-lm" -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -o umcx umcx.o
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccep7zpg.crtoffloadtable.o: warning: relocation against `__offload_funcs_end' in read-only section `.rodata'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
$./umcx cube60

libgomp: Offload data incompatible with GCN plugin (expected 3, received 2)

libgomp: Cannot map target functions or variables (expected 1, have 4294967295)

I am not able to get g++-13 to work.
If I build it with make nvidia CXX=g++-13, I got a different error
g++-13  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=nvptx-none -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -c umcx.cpp -o umcx.o
g++-13  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=nvptx-none -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -o umcx umcx.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-13: fatal error: cannot read spec file ‘libgomp.spec’: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
nvptx mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-13 returned 1 exit status

On a different machine, same xubuntu 22.04 distro, same g++-12/13 installed from ppa, CUDA 12.6, both compilers gave me Value 'sm_30' is not defined for option 'gpu-name' error.
g++-13  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=nvptx-none -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -c umcx.cpp -o umcx.o
g++-13  -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3  -foffload=nvptx-none -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -DGPU_OFFLOAD -fopenmp -o umcx umcx.o
ptxas fatal   : Value 'sm_30' is not defined for option 'gpu-name'
nvptx-as: ptxas returned 255 exit status
nvptx mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-13 returned 1 exit status

so my questions are

what change do I need to make to make g++ build my code for nvptx?
what is the supported mechanism for g++-12/13 to deep-copy dynamic array element of a struct/class to the GPU? I see OpenMP 5.1 example document, Page 181/183 show samples using declare mapper()/map(mapper(id)) for this, but gcc does not yet support mapper.
nvc++ builds the following directives for mapping a dynamic array inside a nested class

map(alloc: inputvol.vol)  map(to: inputvol.vol[0:inputvol.dimxyzt]) map(alloc: outputvol.vol) map(from: outputvol.vol[0:outputvol.dimxyzt]) \

and produced correct results on the GPU. is this supported on gcc?

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Other things to try: use an up-to-date compiler, especially openmp support has significantly improved in the last 3 years. c++filt helps you to make sense of the c++ symbol names. You might be missing some function prototypes where the offloading cannot apply implicit type conversion.

The latest gcc I could install on ubuntu 22.04 via ppa is gcc-13, which I tried, now the error is ptxas fatal   : Value 'sm_30' is not defined for option 'gpu-name'. I added -foffload=-misa=sm_35 as suggested in an online post, but the error remains. My cuda version is 11.5.

Found several threads on this error, but no clear workaround, ref 1, 2, 3, 4.

@Joachim, I updated my post and included the github repo https://github.com/fangq/umcx for my source code (~400 lines) and the commands to build/reproduce the compiler issues. let me know if you are able to see these errors and offer some suggestions how to get around it.

StackOverflow questions are supposed to be stand-alone, i.e. they should not rely on outside websites like GitHub for MREs. Also I would be very surprised if 400 lines is "minimal".

For the "sinf" error, I think you just need to add "-foffload-options=-lm" to the link so the device versions of libm are included.  See: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading.

adding foffload=-lm solved the math function problem! g++-12 were also able to build a binary. However, running the benchmark ./umcx cube60 gave me memory errors libgomp: cuCtxSynchronize error: unspecified launch failure (perhaps abort was called); libgomp: cuMemFree_v2 error: unspecified launch failure; libgomp: device finalization failed. When running compute-sanitizer ./umcx cube60, it complains line#185 of the code, with Invalid global read of size 4 bytes

after adding -foffload=-lm to the Makefile, I have updated the question with the latest error messages from g++-12, with either nvptx or amdgcn offloading, along with commands to reproduce those errors.
